# Count characters and their position in a string

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a string like '###ABC##DE'. I need to find out the position of '#' and then how many '#' after that. For example in this case output should be

```
position count
=======  ======
1           3
7           2
```

Is it possible to do it in sql statement or do we need plsql block here?

Comment: You could store the query results in an array using a script and then do an occurrence search to find each each occurrence of the value you are looking for and return what index each occurrence is located at..

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way of doing it in a SQL statement:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT '###ABC##DE' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'A#B#C#D#E##' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'ABCDE' str FROM dual)
SELECT str,
       NVL(length(regexp_substr(str, '#+', 1, LEVEL)), 0) num_hashes,
       regexp_instr(str, '#+', 1, LEVEL) hash_pos
FROM   sample_data
CONNECT BY regexp_substr(str, '#+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
AND PRIOR str = str
AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL;

STR         NUM_HASHES   HASH_POS
----------- ---------- ----------
###ABC##DE           3          1
###ABC##DE           2          7
A#B#C#D#E##          1          2
A#B#C#D#E##          1          4
A#B#C#D#E##          1          6
A#B#C#D#E##          1          8
A#B#C#D#E##          2         10
ABCDE                0          0
```

What this does is use a hierarchical query (that's the `connect by` part) to go through the string and search for 1 or more # characters. It will output a row for each group.